# How can I export sonarqube metrics to a newer version

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.0

I need to know if it is possible to export all the metrics registered in my sonarqube 4.0 to a newer version "6.2". How should I proceed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to export; simply upgrade. The upgrade process is automated and should go smoothly.

Because there are two LTS versions between where you are and where you want to go, you'll have to perform this in 3 stages:

- 4.0 -> 4.5.7 (previous LTS)
- 4.5.7 -> 5.6.6 (current LTS)
- 5.6.6 -> 6.2

Comment: 6.3 is currently in RC phase. By the time you get this done, it may be GA.

Comment: Hi G. Ann, I expressed myself poorly in the question. I have a sonar inside docker in version 6.2 and sql too, we have nothing configured in sonar just installed. I was able to export the metrics in version 4.0. Is it possible to import this xml file into this new version? Or is it only possible through the upgrade? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Only through the upgrade.